# Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql:///<dbname> error for CloudSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I am trying to connect to my GCP projects PostgreSQL CloudSQL instance from my local machine. The PostgreSQL doesn't have a public IP, only private.

```
    Properties connProps = new Properties();
    connProps.setProperty("user", "XXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com");
    connProps.setProperty("password", "password");
    connProps.setProperty("sslmode", "disable");
    connProps.setProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");
    connProps.setProperty("cloudSqlInstance", "coral-XXX-XXXX:us-central1:mdm");
    connProps.setProperty("enableIamAuth", "true");

    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);
    config.setDataSourceProperties(connProps);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 10s

    HikariDataSource connectionPool = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

I get the below error

> Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql:///mdm
>
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

I have verified that my username, instancename, IAM connectivity is all working fine. The IAM service account I am using is my compute engine's default service account.

Should I be able to connect to this PostgreSQL instance from my local machine?

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help and apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you're configuring your JDBC URL correctly.

The URL should look like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md#creating-the-jdbc-url) for details.

Second, if your Cloud SQL instance is Private IP only, your local machine won't have a network path to it, unless you've explicitly configured one (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/990747/is-it-possible-to-join-a-vpc-from-outside-google) for options).

Generally, the simplest way to connect to a private IP instance is to run a VM in the same VPC as the instance, and connect from that VM.

Answer (score -1):

While it is a good practice from the security point to have only the private IP enabled and remove the public IP from the Cloud SQL instance, there are some considerations to be kept in mind when thinking about the connectivity.

With the Cloud SQL instance having only the private IP enabled there is no direct way in which you can connect to it from the local machine, neither by using private IP nor by using Cloud SQL proxy.

Now, in your case, as you mentioned you have only private IP enabled in the Cloud SQL instance, it seems to be the reason you are getting the error.

To mitigate the error -

If possible, I would suggest you [provision a public IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ip#add)
for the Cloud SQL instance and then try to connect it by correctly
specifying the jdbc URL as mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-postgres.md#creating-the-jdbc-url), which looks something like this -

```
jdbc:postgresql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

Else, if you don’t want to provision a public IP address, to
establish the connection from an external resource you can make use
of a Cloud VPN Tunnel or a VLAN attachment if you have a Dedicated
Interconnect or a Partner Interconnect as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip#vpn).

If you don’t have a Dedicated Interconnect or a Partner Interconnect and you want to use the private IP only then, to connect to the Cloud SQL you can enable port forwarding via a Compute Engine VM instance. This is done in two steps -

- Connect  the Compute Engine to the Cloud SQL instance via the private IP.
- Forward the local machine database connection request to the Compute Engine to reach the Cloud SQL instance through Cloud SQL Proxy tunnel. This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74xJ6LYYcXM) describes how to do this.

To get a detailed description of the above you can go through [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-sql-with-private-ip-only-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-de4ac23ce98a).

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question at all.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Can you elaborate on your comment i.e. why you feel my answer does not address the question, so that I can improve my answer?

Comment: You don't explain what the OP should do to fix their problem.